# How to express the goals of a project, "the pursued outputs of the project", "the essential project outputs", or something else?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Let's say I am a project manager and I would like to state the goals/outputs of my project. I defined 3 project outputs 1), 2) and 3).

How can I say that? I had the idea to do it like that, is it correct?

> The pursued outputs of the project are: 1)..., 2)..., 3)...

or

> The essential project outputs are: 1)..., 2)..., 3)...

Is that grammatically correct? I do not really feel comfortable when structuring those sentences. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can use **"expected"**. It is really not needed to overdo/over-complicate things to make an awesome sentence. A simple sentence with correct grammar and complete information, is as good as it can get.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for something that you hope to achieve in the future, the best choice would be the noun "goal" (or the synonymous *aim* or *purpose)*.

The meaning of the noun [*output*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/output), which is usually uncountable, is quite different, and it is usually related to numbers, amounts, or quantities.

As for which adjective to use with the noun *goal*, is up to you, but the most common in your context may be *primary, main, immediate, ultimate, long-/short-termed, etc.* (You can look for more at any collocations dictionary)

In writing, your sentence might read:

> The (agjective) goals of the project are as follows/are the following:
>
> 1)...
>
> 2)...
>
> 3)...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works:

> - The **essential** outputs of the project are...

**Essential** describes the outputs.

@CinCout suggested:

> - The **expected** outputs of the project are...

**Expected** implies that *someone* is expecting these outputs.  (It could be *us*, or *somebody else*.)

*Pursued project outputs* sounds very awkward because the *subject* (us, we, or the project team) is absent.

These would be fine:

> - We are **pursuing** these **outputs for the project**:
> - We are **pursuing** these **outcomes of the project**:
> - We are **pursuing** these **results of the project**:

(Either 'for' or 'of' sounds fine to me).

You might noticed I avoided using *noun phrases* like **project outputs**.   You are usually safe saying "**outcomes of the project**" or **"instructions for operating the machine"** instead of "**project outcomes**" or **"machine operation instructions"**.

English does allow these *multiple noun phrases*, where other languages (like French or Spanish) usually don't allow them.  They are common in business writing but can sound very awkward.   You could be grammatically correct if you were to say:

> - *Preliminary proposed pursued project outputs:*

but this "word soup" (soup of words) sounds horrible.